# make PHP curl use openssl instead of NSS

Tags: php, openssl, rhel6, curl, nss

Does anyone know how could I force php to use curl with openssl instead of NSS on RHEL 6? 
I've installed [curl-openssl-7.30.0-1.1.el6.x86_64.rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23361523/dir/redhat_el_6/com/curl-openssl-7.30.0-1.1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) but how can I tell php to use it?

Actually is there a way to tell php to use curl with openssl without recompiling php ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK which libraries to use are compile time options and not something that can be changed at run-time.